# org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 0 of

Tags: android, json

Here is my JSON

```
{"result1":[{"pid":"55708","pname":"johnson","unitprice":"42"},{"pid":"16592","pname":"Hamam Soap","unitprice":"30"},{"pid":"02931","pname":"Santoor Soap","unitprice":"26"},{"pid":"71036","pname":"Vivel Soap","unitprice":"50"},{"pid":"25942","pname":"Lux","unitprice":"28"},{"pid":"22658","pname":"Lux","unitprice":"28"},{"pid":"66156","pname":"Olive","unitprice":"50"},{"pid":"16004","pname":"Navaratna Oil","unitprice":"65"},{"pid":"44752","pname":"Lays","unitprice":"20"},{"pid":"62542","pname":"Mysore Sandel","unitprice":"70"},{"pid":"78276","pname":"Chik Shampoo","unitprice":"3"},{"pid":"12629","pname":"Head & shoulders","unitprice":"3"},{"pid":"23524","pname":"ThumsUp","unitprice":"20"},{"pid":"38026","pname":"Dettol Soap","unitprice":"30"}]}
```

It is Valid JSON, But I am getting the same error.

```
        jsonObject=new JSONObject(json_string1);
        jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("result1");

        while (count<jsonArray.length())
        {
            JSONObject jo=jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            pid=jo.getString("pid");
            Product_Name=jo.getString("pname");
            product_Price=jo.getString("unitprice");
        }
```

Comment: Can you add the error message ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to increase count variable like below.

```
int count = 1;
jsonObject=new JSONObject(json_string1);
        jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("result1");

        while (count<jsonArray.length())
        {
            JSONObject jo=jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            pid=jo.getString("pid");
            Product_Name=jo.getString("pname");
            product_Price=jo.getString("unitprice");
            count ++;
        }
```

Error is Here Like

Expected literal value at character 0 of /n{"result1":[{"pid":"55708","pname":"johnson","unitprice":"42"},{"pid":"16592","pname":"Hamam Soap","unitprice":"30"},{"pid":"02931","pname":"Santoor Soap","unitprice":"26"},{"pid":"71036","pname":"Vivel Soap","unitprice":"50"},{"pid":"25942","pname":"Lux","unitprice":"28"},{"pid":"22658","pname":"Lux","unitprice":"28"},{"pid":"66156","pname":"Olive","unitprice":"50"},{"pid":"16004","pname":"Navaratna Oil","unitprice":"65"},{"pid":"44752","pname":"Lays","unitprice":"20"},{"pid":"62542","pname":"Mysore Sandel","unitprice":"70"},{"pid":"78276","pname":"Chik Shampoo","unitprice":"3"},{"pid":"12629","pname":"Head & shoulders","unitprice":"3"},{"pid":"23524","pname":"ThumsUp","unitprice":"20"},{"pid":"38026","pname":"Dettol Soap","unitprice":"30"}]}/n

Comment: Thank u For ur Response,I initialized count value with 0 like count=0;

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me :

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"result1\":[{\"pid\":\"55708\",\"pname\":\"johnson\",\"unitprice\":\"42\"},{\"pid\":\"16592\",\"pname\":\"Hamam Soap\",\"unitprice\":\"30\"},{\"pid\":\"02931\",\"pname\":\"Santoor Soap\",\"unitprice\":\"26\"},{\"pid\":\"71036\",\"pname\":\"Vivel Soap\",\"unitprice\":\"50\"},{\"pid\":\"25942\",\"pname\":\"Lux\",\"unitprice\":\"28\"},{\"pid\":\"22658\",\"pname\":\"Lux\",\"unitprice\":\"28\"},{\"pid\":\"66156\",\"pname\":\"Olive\",\"unitprice\":\"50\"},{\"pid\":\"16004\",\"pname\":\"Navaratna Oil\",\"unitprice\":\"65\"},{\"pid\":\"44752\",\"pname\":\"Lays\",\"unitprice\":\"20\"},{\"pid\":\"62542\",\"pname\":\"Mysore Sandel\",\"unitprice\":\"70\"},{\"pid\":\"78276\",\"pname\":\"Chik Shampoo\",\"unitprice\":\"3\"},{\"pid\":\"12629\",\"pname\":\"Head & shoulders\",\"unitprice\":\"3\"},{\"pid\":\"23524\",\"pname\":\"ThumsUp\",\"unitprice\":\"20\"},{\"pid\":\"38026\",\"pname\":\"Dettol Soap\",\"unitprice\":\"30\"}]}");
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result1");
            int count = 0;

            String pid="", Product_Name="",product_Price="";
            while (count<jsonArray.length())
            {
                JSONObject jo=jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                 pid=jo.getString("pid");
                 Product_Name=jo.getString("pname");
                 product_Price=jo.getString("unitprice");
                 count++;
                 System.out.println(pid + " " + Product_Name +" "+ product_Price);
            }
```

But, be careful with what you re currently doing. Your `while` loop is iterating through the whole result1 array. So your variables `pid` `Product_name` `product_Price` will have the value of the last entry of the array.

Comment: Its Not Working for me @Asew

Comment: @SangeethKumar What is not working ? Can you explain the problem a little bit clearly ? Because this code compile just fine for me.

Comment: its Not showing the Output as well when i Dubug the code its Directly Jumping from  jsonObject=new JSONObject(json_string1); to Catch Block and Showing the Exception like wise.

Comment: Why do you debug the code ? Why dont just you run it? Can you edit your question and post the full message error ?